# How to remove the auto generated div by ajaxcontroltoolkit containing overflow-y: hidden

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit, jquery-chosen

Recently I have started using chosen dropdowns in an already existing web application. Due the generated div by the ajax control toolkit collapsible panel, the dropdowns are not working correctly. They are cut off by overflow-y: hidden.

When I remove this property with inspect element in Chrome (same as firebug) everything works fine. I have done some research but I can't seem to find the solution to my problem.

Here is the generated div (by ajaxcontroltoolkit):

```
<div id="" class="" style="border: 0px; 
 margin: 0px; padding: 0px; overflow-y: hidden; 
 visibility: visible; height: auto; display: block;">
  .......
</div>
```

Below is a picture of the situation, i have brushed it a bit in mspaint, so thats why it looks so bad. Below the image the drowdown stops and there are 2 buttons, after the buttons is the end of the page.

[image]

Lets say below is my normal code, the place of the div in the document is where the comment is.

```
<div class="tempdivso">&nbsp;</div>
<!-- it is generated right here !-->
<asp:Panel ID="collapsibelPanel" runat="server" CssClass="minheight no-overflow">
```

Please tell me what I can do to change the generated overflow-y to visible or remove the div entirely.

Comment: where in the document is the div? is it appended straight to the body?

Comment: If the div really has no ID or class then we need to see some of the surrounding html to figure out how to select the correct element.

Comment: its right above the collapsible panel

Comment: I have added it to the question

Comment: I'm a bit confused.  Looking at the chosen demo page (http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/) the dropdown elements all have classes, and none of them are set to `overflow-y:hidden`

Comment: @archer ajaxcontroltoolkit generates the div, not chosen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally solved the problem by not using AjaxControlToolkit anymore for this panel. Unfortunately this was the only nice and perfect working solution. So I just copied the behaviour by using jQuery show and hide for only this panel.